# Rust how to start an embedded project

Tags: rust, embedded

I'm starting new and I'm looking for the best way to start an embedded project.
I would like to develop a BSP for a specific board and the application in parallel. The BSP will probably be used for futur other project.

I create my project like this:

```bash
cargo new my-app
cd my-app
cargo new --lib bsp
```

So I obtain the following tree:

```bash
├── bsp
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       ├── end_of_stroke.rs
│       ├── led.rs
│       └── lib.rs
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── Embed.toml
├── memory.x
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── main.rs
```

I don't think this is the best way to do it because I can't import my bsp into the main.
main.rs

```rust
#![no_main]
#![no_std]

use panic_halt as _;

use bsp::Bsp;
use cortex_m_rt::entry;

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let bsp = Bsp::init();

    loop {}
}
```

Comment: what's a "BSP"?

Comment: board support package. That include drivers for a specific board

Answer (score -1):

The answer is to use [Cargo workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html)